# Entity Framework code first in data access layer

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0, architecture, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1

I am using N-layer architecure in my project. In the data access layer I use Entity Framework code first.
When I fill an object in the DAL, dispose the context and transfer the object to the business layer, the navigation properties become null.
I have no problem if I don't dispose the context, but my question is it good to dispose
the context?
If yes, how can I solve the problem when I transfer the object to the next layer (business), so that the navigational properties don't become null.
My code in Data access layer:

```
public List<DomainObject.ContractCenter> GetAll()
{
    try
    {
        List<ContractCenter> contractCenters = new List<ContractCenter>();
        using (var context = new DBContext())
        {
            contractCenters = context.ContractCenters.ToList();
        }

        return contractCenters;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your questions:

> is it good to dispose the context?

Yes, the context should be as short-lived as possible (see @khellang's answer regarding UnitOfWork and IOC if you have a possibility to restructure your project and implement cleaner architecture).

> how can i solve the problem when i transfer object to next layer

You need to eager-load the related collections (navigational properties):

```
public List<DomainObject.ContractCenter> GetAll()
{
    try
    {
        using (var context = new DBContext())
        {
            return context.ContractCenters.
                           Include(c => c.YourChildCollection1).
                           Include(c => c.YourChildCollection2).
                           ...
                           ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `DbContext` should be kept alive as long as your "Unit of Work" is active. E.g. If you are making a web-application, it should be created when the request starts, and disposed, at the latest, when the request ends.

In your case, the `DbContext` should be kept alive until you've finished populating your domain model, or else the navigation properties which are being [lazy loaded](http://www.nileshgule.com/2010/09/entity-framework-part-8-lazy-loading.html) will be `null`, as you mentioned. The downside of "detaching" your entities by disposing the `DbContext` when you have populated the model is that you lose state tracking of the entities, and you will need to do this yourself when you want to save the data.

If you don't have *lots* of domain logic I would just add it directly to your code-first POCO entities. In that way, you will still have the state tracking in place.

I would recommend using an IoC container to manage the lifetime of your `DbContext`, as well as the repository or whatever you are using for data access. Maybe in combination with the [Unit of Work pattern](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2009/06/16/using-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-with-entity-framework-4-0.aspx). There are lots to choose from, some of my favorites are

- [Unity](http://unity.codeplex.com/)
- [Ninject](http://www.ninject.org/)
- [Autofac](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/)

There are lots of good tutorials for using an IoC Container to manage lifetime, google it! :)